# How to set audio data in UIPasteboard in IOS

Tags: ios, audio, uipasteboard

I am using UIPasteboard class for copy the media file. Image is successfully added in the UIPasteboard but I can't set the audio data in the UIPasteboard.

So anyone please help me, how do I add audio data in the UIPasteboard?

Currently I am using this code but this does not work:

```
 let past = UIPasteboard.general

 past.items = [["public.mpeg-4":data!]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally I got the answer. We can't set audio content in the `UIPasteBoard` class.